# What is the runtime of this recursive code for computing exponents?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

Would the running time complexity for the following function be `O(1)`?

```
int pow(int a, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n % 2 == 1) {
        return pow(a, n / 2) * pow(a, n / 2) * a;
    } else {
        return pow(a, n / 2) * pow(a, n / 2);
    }
}
```

I was under that impression because there are only if statements in the code, no loops. I've never worked with Big-O and recursion before and I can't find any good resources online.

Comment: Well, it takes constant time if n is 0, otherwise it takes at least twice however many operations pow(a,n/2) takes.

Comment: ahh, okay. So it is O(n) and O(1) in the best case scenario?

Answer (score 5):

The runtime of your function is O(n), but it can easily be modified to run in time O(log n).

There are many ways we can see this. First, we could count up the total number of recursive calls being made, since each recursive call does O(1) work. Imagine, for example, we call pow(a, 8) for some number a. Then

- pow(a, 8) calls pow(a, 4) twice.
- pow(a, 4) calls pow(a, 2) twice.
- pow(a, 2) calls pow(a, 1) twice.
- pow(a, 1) calls pow(a, 0) twice.

This means that there is

- 1 call to pow(a, 8),
- 2 calls to pow(a, 4),
- 4 calls to pow(a, 2),
- 8 calls to pow(a, 1), and
- 16 calls to pow(a, 0).

Overall, this is 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 31 total calls made.

Now, suppose we call pow(a, 16). That will fire off two calls to pow(a, 8) (62 total recursive calls made), plus one for the initial call to pow(a, 16) for a total of 63 recursive calls. If we called pow(a, 32), we'd make two calls to pow(a, 16) (126 total recursive calls), plus one for the initial call to pow(a, 32) for a total of 127 recursive calls. More generally, it seems like if we call pow(a, n), we'd get 4n - 1 calls made, which would be O(n).

We can actually formally prove this. Let C(n) be the number of calls made on an input of size n. Notice that

> C(0) = 1.
>   C(n) = 2C(n / 2) + 1

This recurrence solves, via the Master Theorem, to O(n).

Notice that each individual recursive call is doing very little work. What kills us is the fact that there are so many total recursive calls being made that the work adds up across those calls. But while there are a lot of *total* recursive calls being made, there are very few *unique* recursive calls being made. So consider this variation on the code:

```
int pow(int a, int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;

    int halfPow = pow(a, n / 2);
    if (n % 2 == 0) return halfPow * halfPow;
    else return halfPow * halfPow * a;
}
```

This code caches the value of the recursive call that's being made, so it always fires off a single call each time. As a result, the work done per call is still O(1), but there's no more branching in the recursion. Then, since each recursive call has a size that's half that of the original, *and because there's only one call per level*, the runtime works out to O(log n), which you can confirm using the Master Theorem.

In general, be wary of arguments of the form "we keep cutting things in half, so the overall work ends up being O(log n)." That may be true, but the amount of work you do at each step is also very, very important for determining the runtime, as you can see here.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down what is happening here. It is in fact O(n). For each call to pow() there are two options that can happen:

1. Return 0 -- which is a single operation.
2. Perform two calls to pow() with n/2.

So, while you reduce your n by n/2 on each call to pow(), you increase your problem space exponentially on each step. First step of recursion is two calls to pow, second is 2^2, third is 2^3, etc. For n = 16 will have pow(..., 16), pow(..., 8), pow(..., 4), pow(..., 2), pow(..., 1), pow(..., 0) with 2^0 calls to pow for n = 16, 2^1 for n = 8, 2^2 for n = 4, 2^3 for n = 2, 2^4 for n = 1, 2^5 for n = 0.

So, we call pow log(n) times but each iteration of pow calls double the number of calls in the previous step. This means we have O(n)

Comment: It doesn't cash the result of `pow(a,n/2)`, so it is `O(n)`.

Comment: It's recursing on each iteration of the call to pow(a, n/2). They are added to the stack until they hit the terminating condition of n == 0. Number of computations required to get to the end is O(log(n))

Comment: It doesn't cash the result of `pow(a,n/2)` and calculates it twice each iteration. At the end of iteration, `pow` is called `O(n)` times.

Comment: @DannyuNDos "cash" -> "cache"

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry about the typo, but no, I'll show I'm right by a diagram.

Comment: @DannyuNDos No worries. They sound the same and English is an amazingly stupid language when it comes to managing duplication.

Comment: I updated my answer to be correct and walk through it. I neglected to think through the problem. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

No, because it involves recursion and branching. Its time complexity is `O(n)`, and its space complexity is `O(log n)`.

You'll get `O(log n)` time complexity with:

```
int pow (int a, int n) {
    if(n == 0) { return 1; }
    int halfpow = pow(a,n/2);
    return halfpow * halfpow * (n % 2 == 1 ? a : 1);
}
```

Comment: O(n) means for n=100 there will be 100 iterations. In this case there are only 8 (100, 50, 25, 12, 6, 3, 1, 0) iterations.

Comment: @user4581301 No. It will be (100, 50, 50, 25, 25, 25, 25, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, and 128 0s).

Comment: @PeteBecker This satisfies `O(n)`. If n=8, there will be (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) at the end. If n=16, there will be (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) at the end. And so on.

Comment: @user4581301 - "O(n) means for n=100 there will be 100 iterations." No, that's not what O(n) means. It means that, for large values of n, if you double the value of n you double the number of operations required to compute the result. It says nothing about the actual number of operations required. (Edited from original to clarify what this is responding to)

Comment: Your analysis of the time and space complexity are right, but the justification of "because it involves recursion" is incorrect. It's the *branching* in the recursion that hurts, not the recursion itself.